# how to get hostname and host ip address and saved to variable using shell script?(Linux)

Tags: linux, shell-script

I want to get host name and (single) host address and save it to variable of type string using a `bash` shell script. Currently I am using c program but I want to do this using shell script.

```
hostname = gethostname(hostbuffer, sizeof(hostbuffer)); 

// To retrieve host information 
host_entry = gethostbyname(hostbuffer); 

// To convert an Internet network 
// address into ASCII string 
IPbuffer = inet_ntoa(*((struct in_addr*) 
           host_entry->h_addr_list[0]));
```

Comment: Does the system only ever have one network interface?

Comment: yes..............

Comment: Have you tried anything at all yet? If so, what? (So's we don't repeat your effort.)

Comment: What shell are you using? In the `zsh` shell, the host name is already in `$HOST`, and `bash` has `$HOSTNAME`.

Answer (score 3):

To get the full hostname, use `hostname -f`:

```
hn=$(hostname -f)
```

To get the local IP adress, use `hostname -I`:

```
ip=$(hostname -I)
```

Comment: @roaima I got the correct result on Ubuntu 16.04 with `-i`, but the wrong one on 18.04. Thanks for the heads up.

Comment: @raghu121 yes, this is bash. What do you mean?

Comment: I am getting 2 Ip address but I want first one